# Extending string formatting with custom conversion types

Tags: python, string-formatting

[string.Formatter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter) allows the extension of new style formatting with custom conversion types.

Is this possible for the older `"%"`-style formatting strings too? Is there a library for this?

Comment: if you overload the `%` op...

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
class CustomFormat(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.Object = obj

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Object).upper()  # your magic goes here...

print "abc%s" % customFormat("hello")
# abcHELLO
```